# How do I dynamically generate an element with a tag name based on a prop?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm interested in building a reusable `<Element>` React component for my particular purposes. The intent is for whomever using it to optionally specify a `tagName` prop that dictates the exact HTML element into which the component will compile. As it stands, here is what the `Element` component looks like:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';    

class Element extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.mapToElement = new Map([
      ['ARTICLE', (props, children) => (<article {...props}>{children}</article>)],
      ['ASIDE', (props, children) => (<aside {...props}>{children}</aside>)],
      ['DIV', (props, children) => (<div {...props}>{children}</div>)],
      ['FOOTER', (props, children) => (<footer {...props}>{children}</footer>)],
      ['HEADER', (props, children) => (<header {...props}>{children}</header>)],
      ['MAIN', (props, children) => (<main {...props}>{children}</main>)],
      ['P', (props, children) => (<p {...props}>{children}</p>)],
      ['SECTION', (props, children) => (<section {...props}>{children}</section>)],
      ['SPAN', (props, children) => (<span {...props}>{children}</span>)]
    ]);
  }

  render() {
    const {
      children,
      tagName = 'DIV',
      ...rest
    } = this.props;

    return (this.mapToElement.get(tagName.toUpperCase())(rest, children));
  }
};
```

As can be seen, however, the ability for this component to successfully work is driven by a rather verbose mapping of [HTML `tagName`s](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) to their corresponding JSX syntax. I'd optimally like to make this component have support for all non-self-closing HTML elements, but would obviously like to do so without being forced to expand this mapping to include every possible HTML element fitting that criterion.

Is there a more dynamic, future-proof means for doing so and, if so, what might that look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're just creating a wrapper for [`React.createElement`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-api.html#createelement) which is what all JSX is transpiled into to create your elements:

```
render() {
  const {
    children,
    tagName = 'div',
    ...rest
  } = this.props;

  return React.createElement(tagName, rest, children);
}
```

Thus:

```
<Element tagName="span" foo="bar">
  Foobar!
</Element>
```

Will become (once transpiled):

```
React.createElement('span', {
  foo: 'bar'
}, 'Foobar!');
```

Which is the same as:

```
<span foo="bar">Foobar!</span>
```

And if you only ever wanted to restrict it to just DOM elements and not custom React components, just restrict the proptype or validate the type yourself:

```
tagName: PropType.string.isRequired
```

Or even your own validator:

```
tagName: (props, propName, componentName) => {
  if(typeof props[propName] !== 'string') {
    return new Error(`The ${propName} prop should be a string in ${componentName}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: jeeeezz... I feel dumb. I've become so accustomed to ES6-style React code, I had completely forgotten that the `createElement` method is still available to us. You're 100% spot on with what I was looking for. Thanks @AndrewLi

Comment: @IsenrichO No problem, it happens to the best of us. Cheers!

Comment: I'm more inclined toward using a custom validator in this situation. This seems like the best place to warn against self-closing HTML tags. Although I still don't see a more efficient way of having such validation work that isn't based on checking against a list of those forbidden tags. Something like,  `if (['BR', 'HR', 'IMAGE', 'INPUT', 'META', 'SOURCE', 'TRACK', 'WBR'].includes(propName.toUpperCase())) { // throw error }`

Comment: @IsenrichO Well, I'm not aware of any way to get the list of self closing tags so that would be the only ways, sadly.